# d3.js - show git history graph with d3 force simulation

Tags: d3.js

I would like to show some git history with d3 force simulation. I would like the output graph similar as gitk tool. current output only show one line.

```js
var width = 800
var height = 400

var margin = {top:50,left:80,right:50,bottom:50}

var gwidth = width + margin.left + margin.right
var gheight = height + margin.top + margin.bottom

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('height',gheight)
    .attr('width',gwidth)
    .style('border','2px solid red')

var g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform',`translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)

var csvtext =`sha1,parent,tags,subject
4089c04,,,initial commit
1755891,4089c04,,blank files
6d02945,1755891,,commit bad things
892f437,6d02945,,updated config for new version
3ed7869,892f437,,added ruby-lint and fixed the demo repo for latest pre-commit repo
22b313e,3ed7869,,Update scss-lint to point at new mirror.
1bf55e4,22b313e,,Add jshint.
a17804e,1bf55e4,,Add moar fail.
e4bb28e,a17804e,,Update readme
06bed9d,e4bb28e,,Merge pull request #1 from pre-commit/update_readme
06bed9d,a17804e,,Merge pull request #1 from pre-commit/update_readme
2c0d4c4,06bed9d,,Update pre-commit config.
0bf7ab8,2c0d4c4,,Update pre-commit-config
b7d25c0,0bf7ab8,,Update README instructions
5bfff42,b7d25c0,,Add end-of-file-fixer
61fd2e4,5bfff42,,Add failure demo image.
e2c64de,61fd2e4,,Add commit demo image.
1d464cb,e2c64de,,Update hooks
33d0715,1d464cb,,Run pre-commit autoupdate
dae03c1,33d0715,,Normalize git urls in pre-commit config
f667c62,dae03c1,,Merge pull request #2 from pre-commit/all-repos_autofix_all-repos-sed
f667c62,33d0715,,Merge pull request #2 from pre-commit/all-repos_autofix_all-repos-sed
f3c315c,f667c62,,Ran pre-commit autoupdate
70bc423,f3c315c,,Add pre-commit install command to README
e1cc669,70bc423,,Merge pull request #3 from nicolaiarocci/patch-1
e1cc669,f3c315c,,Merge pull request #3 from nicolaiarocci/patch-1
50843aa,e1cc669,,pre-commit autoupdate
e1ad72c,50843aa,,flake8 => pycqa/flake8
979b1b1,e1ad72c,,flake8 is on github now
267690c,979b1b1,,Merge pull request #5 from graingert/patch-1
267690c,e1ad72c,,Merge pull request #5 from graingert/patch-1
356a67a,267690c,,Update default branch to main
a337a6d,356a67a,"HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD",Merge pull request #8 from pre-commit/all-repos_autofix_master-to-main
a337a6d,267690c,"HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD",Merge pull request #8 from pre-commit/all-repos_autofix_master-to-main
`
var data = d3.csvParse(csvtext)

draw(data)

function draw(data) {
    var nodes = []
    var id = 'sha1'
    var parent = 'parent'
    
    data.forEach(function(d, i) {
    var n = nodes.find(function(p) {
        return p.child === d[id];
    })
    if (n) {
        n.parents.push(d[parent])
    }else{
        nodes.push({child:d[id],level:0,parents:[d[parent]]})
    }
    });

    ready(g,width,height,nodes)
}

function ready(g,width,height,data) {
    var radius = 5;
    var nodes = []
    var levelRadius = 10

    data.forEach(function(d, i) {
    var n = data.find(function(p) {
        return p.child === d.parents[0];
    })
    if (n) {
        d.level = d.parents.length? n.level + 1 : 0;
    }else{
        d.level = d.parents.length?  1 : 0;
    }

    d.dy = d.y = d.level * levelRadius * 2;
    d.x = width / 2 - i * levelRadius;
    });
    var max_level = d3.max(data,d => d.level)

    var nodes = data;

    var links = [];
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    node.parents.forEach(function(parentId) {
        var parentNode = nodes.find(function(d) {
        return d.child === parentId;
        });

        if (parentNode != null) {
        links.push({
        id: parentNode.child + " - " + node.child,
        source: parentNode,
        target: node,
        });
        }
    });
    });

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(levelRadius))
    .force("x", d3.forceX()
           .x(function(d) {
           return width / 2;
           })
           .strength(10)
          )
    .force("y", d3.forceY()
           .y(function(d) {
           return d.dy;
           })
           .strength(10.5)
          );

    simulation.tick(200).stop();

    var link = g.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr('fill','none')
    .attr('stroke','black')
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        return (
        "M" +
        d.source.x +
        "," +
        d.source.dy +
        " C " +
        d.source.x +
        "," +
        (d.source.y + d.target.dy) / 2 +
        " " +
        d.target.x +
        "," +
        (d.source.y + d.target.dy) / 2 +
        " " +
        d.target.x +
        "," +
        d.target.dy
        );
    });
    
    var node = g
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.dy] + ")";
    });

    node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr('fill','black')
    .attr('stroke','black')
    
    node.append("text")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
    .attr("dx", radius + 3)
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.child;
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(0)" 
        });
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@7.0.4/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

gitk output:

[image]